# How do I check if a parameter given to a function is a list?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I will like the function to return a comment if the parameter given to a not a list. If it's a list, I'll like to perform some operation.

below is the code:

```
def manipulate_data(*num):
  if type(num) is not list:
    return "Only lists allowed"
  else:
    positive = 0
    for n in num:
        if n >= 0:
            positive = positive + 1
```

Comment: And _what_ is your problem?

Comment: The type of `num` is always `tuple`. Remove the `*` and the code will work.

Comment: `if not isinstance(num, list):`

Comment: @ettanany positive is already outside the for, no need to move it outside the if scope

Comment: use isinstance() in python.

Answer (score 0):

By using the *nums argument you are packaging all the arguments into a list. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) may be useful.

`manipulate_data(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` will result in `num = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` while `manipulate_data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`will result in `num = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],)` that is a tuple with only one element. Remove the * or if needing to process multiple lists as arguments use a loop to do the check on every tuple element.

```
def manipulate_data(num):
  if type(num) is not list:
    return "Only lists allowed"
  else:
    positive = 0
    for n in num:
        if n >= 0:
            positive += 1
    return positive
def manipulate_multiple(*nums):
  for num in nums:
    manipulate_data(num)
```

Remember this function is not returning anything yet

Comment: your answer has pointed me to the right direction, however, what I want to do is perform an operation with the list supplied. for example, if the list supplied is    [1, 3, 2, 3], I want to be able to return the sum of the elements in the list, the example should return    9. The code is returning 1

Comment: @Weirdsourcer the function was not returning everything as I mentioned, edited it to return the number of positives as it was counting them. For adding all the elements try `sum(num)`

Answer (score -1):

ok, make it more clean, except a, b ,all left positional parameter will be pass to c

```
>>> def func(a, b, *c):
...     print a
...     print b
...     print c
```

...

```
>>> func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

1
2
(3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: The answer does not explain the user why this happens or where to find documentation on this. At least giving some keywords for googling should have been done